# Sourcing an rcfile within a parentheses-subshell in Bash?

Tags: bash

In zsh, a subshell created via parentheses can have an rcfile sourced to use commands which may be aliases, only available when specific directories are added to `PATH`, etc.:

```
~ » /bin/zsh -c "workon"
zsh:1: command not found: workon
------------------------------------------------------------
~ » /bin/zsh -c "source ~/.zshrc; workon"
env1
env2
env3
... (expected output)
```

However, the same is not true with bash:

```
~ » /bin/bash -c "workon"
/bin/bash: workon: command not found
------------------------------------------------------------
~ » /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc; workon"
/bin/bash: workon: command not found
------------------------------------------------------------
~ » bash
sean@helium:~$ workon
env1
env2
env3
... (expected output)
```

Is there any way a bash subshell can source an rcfile?

---

To get a head-start on "X-Y problem" responses, this is for a script called `in`:

```
#!/bin/zsh
(source ~/.zshrc; cd $1; ${@:2})
```

I have a directory full of projects (using git) where I often forget if I have left anything uncommitted, so `in` allows me to quickly write `$ in ProjectDir/ git status`, rather than `$ (cd ProjectDir; git status)` (the former feels easier to type than the latter).

Preferably, I would like this script usable with bash (which is why I ask, even though it works currently with zsh).

Comment: The standard answer is to use exported functions instead of aliases, eg `workon() { ...; }; export workon`. Alternatively, make `workon` a script in one of the directories in `$PATH`.

Comment: @AFH `workon` is actually an exported function, part of a Python package called `virtualenvwrapper`, my apologies for mislabeling it an alias.

Comment: I think you don't need `(…)` in your `in` script (if you run it in `bash`).

Comment: "Preferably, I would like this script usable with bash" – This I don't understand. You can run `in` from within `bash` if your `$PATH` is right, regardless of the script shebang. If it works when interpreted by `zsh`, why do you need to change it?

Comment: I apologise: I omitted `-f` from the `export` in my definition of `workon` - it should have been `workon() { ...; }; export -f workon`. Exported functions should work in any subshell, so `workon` ought to be found without needing to run `~/.bashrc` beforehand (`PATH` is exported). With this or an equivalent definition, `bash -c workon` should be sufficient, though I don't see why you would use `bash -c` at all. By the way, you do not need the brackets around the second line of `in`, since scripts run in a subshell (unless invoked with `source`), and you don't need a further level of subshell.

Answer (score 1):

In my Kubuntu the first thing `.bashrc` does is this:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I guess your `.bashrc` is similar. This is why `/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc; …"` "doesn't" source. If you used `bash -i -c …` then `.bashrc` would be sourced automatically and your `source` would parse it unnecessarily for the second time.